# OnActivityResult() not being called when using a Camera intent?

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin.android

I am trying to make a page (lets call it page #2) within my Xamarin.Android app that has a button, when you press on that button the camera app opens. Then you take a picture, accept the picture you took, and then you should be brought back to the page that originally had the camera button on it (page #2), and the image you took will be displayed there under the button.

The problem is that my overridden OnActivityResult() method never gets called after you accept the picture. You press the button, the camera app opens, you take a picture, accept the picture, the camera app closes and you are brought back to the page BEFORE the camera button page (so you're on page #1 now). I think the camera app itself is crashing? I am not sure how to find those logs. Sometimes a popup will show that says "Unfortunately, the camera has stopped." I am guessing that it is the way I am trying to save the photo taken to the phone itself? The only errors I have seen are within the device log, and occasionally it will throw a permission error saying I dont have access to write to the storage device on the phone, but I have the "write" permissions in the manifest file. I am targeting API 26.

Any ideas?

Here is the method for clicking the button:

```
private int PIC_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private ImageView imageView;
private Java.IO.File image;

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
      if (takePictureIntent.ResolveActivity(PackageManager) != null)
      {
        try
        {
          // Create an image file name
          string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
          string imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
          Java.IO.File storageDir = GetExternalFilesDir(global::Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
          Java.IO.File image = Java.IO.File.CreateTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
          );

          global::Android.Net.Uri photoURI = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(ApplicationContext, PackageName + ".fileprovider", image);
          takePictureIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, photoURI);
          takePictureIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);

          StartActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PIC_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          //Not sure what to do, but here's a break point at least.
          Toast.MakeText(this, "blah blah something went wrong", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
      }
    }
```

And here is my simple OnActivityResult that gets skipped/ never called:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
      if (requestCode == PIC_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Result.Ok)
      {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You mean have an if(resultCode != Result.Ok) inside of the OnActivityResult()? The code never goes into the OnActivityResult() method _at all_. So I cannot check that if() statement anyways.

Comment: I tested the code your provided. After capturing the image and selecting the tick, the `OnActivityResult` would be triggered.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT right, it would be. But it doesn't get triggered for me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the current issue of the OnActivityResult() not being called. At the top above the class I was declaring

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/page_name", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, NoHistory = true)]
```

The important note here is the "NoHistory=True" apparently that makes the page exit and return back to the previous page. Deleting the "NoHistory=true" worked and made it so the OnActivityResult() gets called. Some documentation about it says "A value of 'true' means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it" so I guess that makes sense.